# How to store template class objects in a container when they use different template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a class with which I'm wrapping some information, for example:

```
template<typename T>
class Type
{
pubilc:
    Type(const T value) : m_value(value) {}
    T GetValue() const { return m_value; }
private:
    T m_value;
};
```

And I want to store a bunch of these in a container. But to do this they all need to use the same template param. To work around this I have been doing:

```
class TypeBase
{}

template<typename T>
class Type : public TypeBase
{
pubilc:
    Type(const T value) : m_value(value) {}
    T GetValue() const { return m_value; }
private:
    T m_value;
};
```

and storing `TypeBase*` in my container.

Is there a better way to work around this?

Comment: Given the code you posted, if you store `TypeBase*` in a container, how would you utilize each item if you iterate through the container?  Not saying that storing `TypeBase*` can't be done, but you need some sort of virtual function in `TypeBase` or additional template magic to make use of the container.

Comment: So you're wanting to do something like this: `std::vector<Type<T>> container; Type<int> i; Type<float> f; container.push_back(i); container.push_back(f);` .. then iterate over the `container` and perform some action on the underlying type/data?

Comment: If the possible `T` are known, `boost::variant` may help.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I would have some sort of virtual function that actually accomplishes something; the code was just to illustrate what I'm going.